# Error oe_runmake failed bitbake?

Tags: ubuntu, yocto, bitbake

I have a poky setup on Ubuntu 14.04. I have the following layers here:

```
    NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "Ubuntu-14.04"
TARGET_SYS        = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE           = "apalis-imx6"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2.3"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "arm armv7a vfp thumb neon       callconvention-hard       cortexa9"
TARGET_FPU        = "hard"
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    = "morty:a3765887d3efa4c464ef7a00450f218ae2b15eb2"
meta-toradex-nxp  = "morty:c4f34b34bf34f44b974a7add623cafff17d880ad"
meta-toradex-bsp-common = "morty:bb3fafea5a3094909c8d7fb3216c37210fcfc339"
meta-freescale    = "morty:05681fdf8298bb441c15135eae424c7601b07e98"
meta-freescale-3rdparty = "morty:e55167c3c2770c07a475342f99cc2a3a23fbfa0c"
oe-meta-go        = "master:0712320950adf810fb324d49fba5d49ae19981b0"
meta-toradex-tegra = "morty:8deaad62384fbe4f4079f62bb7fdfa70ef199236"
```

When I run bitbake core-image-minimal I get:

```
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: m4-native-1.4.17-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: m4-native-1.4.17-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/temp/log.do_compile.11055)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/temp/log.do_compile.11055
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8 infodir=/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/share/info
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| make  all-recursive
| make[1]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build'
| Making all in .
| make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build'
| Making all in examples
| make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/examples'
| make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/examples'
| Making all in lib
| make[2]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/lib'
| make  all-am
| make[3]: Entering directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/lib'
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o clean-temp.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/clean-temp.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o basename-lgpl.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/basename-lgpl.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o stripslash.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/stripslash.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o execute.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/execute.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o exitfail.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/exitfail.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o fatal-signal.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/fatal-signal.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o fd-hook.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/fd-hook.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o fd-safer-flag.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/fd-safer-flag.c
| In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:959:0,
|                  from ./stdlib.h:36,
|                  from ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/clean-temp.c:29:
| /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h: In function ‘wctomb’:
| /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h:90:3: error: #error "Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong"
|  # error "Assumed value of MB_LEN_MAX wrong"
|    ^
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o dup-safer-flag.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/dup-safer-flag.c
| gcc  -std=gnu99  -I. -I../../m4-1.4.17/lib   -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include  -isystem/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o filenamecat.o ../../m4-1.4.17/lib/filenamecat.c
| make[3]: *** [clean-temp.o] Error 1
| make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/lib'
| make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build/lib'
| make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/build'
| make: *** [all] Error 2
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/rama/repositories/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.17-r0/temp/log.do_compile.11055)
ERROR: Task (/home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.17.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 161 tasks of which 153 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/rama/repositories/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.17.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

And the bitbaking stops.
All my layers are on morty, except oe-meta-go.
I also have the problem that it tries to download something and gets stuck for a while and then stops bitbaking. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You omitted the actual error statements for both your two problems... Thus we can help you. You're also not correct when you state that all layers except one are on morty. Your first paste indicates a mix of morty and pyro, except for oe-meta-go, which is on master.

Comment: I apologise, I pasted the wrong setup, the above is the setup I have on my computer

Comment: As i described in another question I also tried to just download a whole working setup, it also gives me the seem error, I dont seem to see what I am missing or why it does not compile?

Comment: I added the whole error statement here

Comment: first clean the source and compile again

Comment: done, still getting same error

Comment: I mean bitbake -c cleansstate m4-native after that bitbake -c clean m4-native then bitbake m4-native

Comment: did that, no improvement